# java.jms.Message in a Method using camel route

Tags: jms, apache-camel, spring-jms

I am using spring-based camel routing. I want to route message to a method which accepts *java.jms.Message* since I have to extract some properties. These properties are set by someone else with a map in message header.

following is my camel config

```
< camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        autoStartup="true">
< route id="testRoute" autoStartup="true" >
 < from uri="activemq:success.queue" />
 < to uri="bean:testService?method=testMessage" />
< /route>
< /camelContext>
```

following is my method signature

```
public void testMessage(java.jms.Message message){
    //extract some header properties and process them
}
```

can it be done? if yes, then how to do it..what exactly am I missing??

(accepting byte array work but not of any use to me, I want entire Message)

if *java.jms.Message* can not be used, then is there any other way I can access those Message header/properties(camel context or something)

**Note: I am NOT supposed to use MessageListener, I have to do it using camel routing only.**

Answer (score 0):

Camel wrapps this for you by placing JMS properties into Camel headers.

```
public void testMessage(Exchange e){
    String myHeader = e.getIn().getHeader("MyHeader",String.class);
}
```

while that might be just what you want, you can also automatically take headers as input through parameter binding.

```
public void testMessage(@Header("JMSCorrelationID") String correlationID, @Header("JMSDestination") Destination dest, @Body byte[] body) {
     // do stuff 
  }
```